# How to define an angular route with an optional path prefix

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

We are currently using ui-router to mount a route globally (`/foo`) and within a path prefix `/projects/:projectid/foo` with the same route definition for `foo`.

In ui-router, this is quite easy by defining an optional path parameter that gets squashed:

```
  {
    name: 'root',
    url: '/{projects}/{projectId}',
    component: BaseComponent,
    params: {
      projectPath: {type: 'path', value: null, squash: true},
      projects: {type: 'path', value: null, squash: true},
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    parent: 'root',
    component: FooComponent,
    url: '/foo'
  }
```

This definition will match both `/projects/<id>/foo` and `/foo` to the same route. Now imagine in our project, there are quite a number of routes that may live globally or within a project context.

Is there a way to achieve this with angular router without duplicating all the routes to be defined once globally and per project?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes:
https://angular.io/api/router/Route#matcher

something like this maybe? Quickly had a look :
https://medium.com/@brandontroberts/custom-route-matching-with-the-angular-router-fbdd48665483

Comment: Thanks Inge, I will take a look at that!